# Problem decoding h264 over RTP TCP stream

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, rtp

I'm trying to receive RTP stream encoding h264 over TCP from my intercom Hikvision DS-KH8350-WTE1. By reverse engineering I was able to replicate how Hikvision original software Hik-Connect on iPhone and iVMS-4200 on MacOS connects and negotaties streaming. Now I'm getting the very same stream as original apps - verified through Wireshark. Now I need to "make sense" of the stream. I know it's RTP because I inspected how iVMS-4200 uses it using `/usr/bin/sample` on MacOS. Which yields:

```
  ! :               2 CStreamConvert::InputData(void*, int)  (in libOpenNetStream.dylib) + 52  [0x11ff7c7a6]
+     ! :                 2 SYSTRANS_InputData  (in libSystemTransform.dylib) + 153  [0x114f917f2]
+     ! :                   1 CRTPDemux::ProcessH264(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)  (in libSystemTransform.dylib) + 302  [0x114fa2c04]
+     ! :                   | 1 CRTPDemux::AddAVCStartCode()  (in libSystemTransform.dylib) + 47  [0x114fa40f1]
+     ! :                   1 CRTPDemux::ProcessH264(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int)  (in libSystemTransform.dylib) + 476  [0x114fa2cb2]
+     ! :                     1 CRTPDemux::ProcessVideoFrame(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int)  (in libSystemTransform.dylib) + 1339  [0x114fa29b3]
+     ! :                       1 CMPEG2PSPack::InputData(unsigned char*, unsigned int, FRAME_INFO*)  (in libSystemTransform.dylib) + 228  [0x114f961d6]
+     ! :                         1 CMPEG2PSPack::PackH264Frame(unsigned char*, unsigned int, FRAME_INFO*)  (in libSystemTransform.dylib) + 238  [0x114f972fe]
+     ! :                           1 CMPEG2PSPack::FindAVCStartCode(unsigned char*, unsigned int)  (in libSystemTransform.dylib) + 23  [0x114f97561]`
```

I can catch that with lldb and see the arriving packet data making sense as the format I'm describing.

The packet signatures look following:

> 0x24 0x02 0x05 0x85 0x80 0x60 0x01 0x57 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x27 0xde
> 0x0d 0x80 0x60 0x37 0x94 0x71 0xe3 0x97 0x10 0x77 0x20 0x2c 0x51 | 0x7c
> 0x85 0xb8 0x00 00 00 00 01 65 0xb8 0x0 0x0 0xa 0x35 ...
>
> 0x24 0x02 0x05 0x85 0x80 0x60 0x01 0x58 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x02 0x00 0x00 0x27 0xde
> 0xd 0x80 0x60 0x37 0x95 0x71 0xe3 0x97 0x10 0x77 0x20 0x2c 0x51 | 0x7c 0x05 0x15 0xac ...
>
> 0x24 0x02 0x5 0x85 0x80 0x60 0x01 0x59 0x00 0x0 0x00 0x02 0x00 00x0 0x27 0xde
> 0xd 0x80 0x60 0x37 0x96 0x71 0xe3 0x97 0x10 0x77 0x20 0x2c 0x51 | 0x7c 0x05 0x5d 0x00 ...

By the means of reverse engineering the original software I was able to figure out that `0x7c85` indicates a key frame. `0x7c85` bytes in the genuine software processing do get replaced by h264 `00 00 00 01 65` Key frame NALU . That's h264 appendix-B format.
The `0x7c05` packets always follow and are the remaining payload of the key frame. No NALU are added during their handling (the `0x7c05` is stripped away and rest of the bytes is copied). None of the bytes preceding 0x7cXX make it to a mp4 recording (that makes sense as it's the RTP protocol , albeit I'm not sure if it's entirely RTP standard or there's something custom from Hikvision).

If you pay close attention in the Header there are 2 separate bytes indicating order which always match, so I'm sure no packet loss is occurring.

I also observed nonkey frames arriving as `0x7c81` and converted to `00 00 00 01 61` NALU but I want to focus solely on the single key frame for now. Mostly because if I record a movie with the original software it will always begin with `00 00 00 01 65` Key frame (that obviously makes sense).

To get a working mp4 I decided to copy paste a mp4 header of a genuine iVMS-4200 recording (in this sense that's every byte preceding 1st frame NALU `00 00 00 01 65` in the mp4 file). I know that the resolution will match the actual camera footage. With the strategy of waiting for a keyframe , replacing `0x7c85` with `00 00 00 01 65` NALU and appending the remaining bytes, or only appending bytes in the `0x7c05` case I do seem to get something that eventually could work.
When I attempt to `ffplay` the custom crafted `mp4` result I do get something (with a little stretch of imagination that's actually the camera fisheye image forming), but clearly there is a problem.

[image]

It seems around 3-4th `0x7c05` packet (as the failing packet differs on every run), when I copy bytes eventually the h264 stream is incorrect. Just by eye-inspecting the bytes I don't see anything unusual.

This is the failing packet around offset 750 decimal, (I know it's around this place because I keep stripping bytes away to see if there's still same amount frame arriving before it breaks).
[image]
More over I did dump those bytes from original software using lldb taking out my own python implementation out of equation. And I run into very same problem with the original packets.

The mp4 header I use should work (since it does for original recordings even if I manipulate number of frames and leave just the first keyframe).
Correct me if I'm wrong but the phase of converting this to MPEG2-PS (which iVMS-4200 does and I don't) should be entirely optional and should not be related to my problem.

**Update**:
I went the path of setting up recording and only then dumping the original iVMS-4200 packets. I edited the recorded movie to only contain keyframe of interest and it works. I found differences but I cannot explain where they are there yet:
[image]
Somehow `00 00 01 E0  13 FA 88 00 02 FF FF` is inserted in the genuine recording (that's 4th packet), but I have no idea how this byte string was generated and what is its purpose.
When I fixed the first difference the next one is:
[image]
The pattern is striking. But what`00 00 01 E0  13 FA 88 00 02 FF FF` actually is? And why is it inserted after `18 03 25 10` & `2F F4 80 FC`
The `00 00 01 E0` signature would suggest those are Packetized Elementary Stream (PES) headers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going for mp4 container wasn't a good choice after all. It turns out the RTP essentially yields raw h264 stream. To inspect its structure I converted the genuine mp4 recording to .264 like this:

```
ffmpeg -i recording.mp4 -codec copy recording.264
```

It's essentially a PPS (`00 00 00 01 67`) and SPS `00 00 00 01 68` followed by frame data NALUs that I got in the stream.

Raw h264 turned out a way simpler structure to aim at, and I don't have to deal with those Packetized Elementary Stream (PES) headers anymore. That yields correct image. In my case I just took the PPS & SPS settings that original recordings use from `recording.264`. That could definitely be resolved dynamically somehow but I didn't bother.